# Can I associate a Twilio recording with the child called that initiated it?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

So here's my issue:

- I initiate a Twilio call via the API
- When the call is picked up, Twilio reaches out to my Twiml server and gets a response containing the following (notice the "record" parameter of the Dial verb):

```html
<Dial callerId="555-555-5555" record="record-from-ringing">
 <Number statusBallbackEvent="completed" statusCallbackMethod="POST" statusCallback="https://myCallback.com">
  555-555-5556
 </Number>
</Dial>
```

The call gets placed and is recorded correctly, but the value of Call Sid for the recording is always the Sid of the parent call.  This can be problematic if I use multiple Dial verbs during the course of one call.

Is there a way to figure out which child call initiated the recording?

Answer (score 0):

To grab your child call SID, I'd recommend using an action URL in the  verb that originates it. A request to this action URL would return the 'DialCallSid' parameter in Twilio's response:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action-parameters

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/dial_callstatus.xml -->
<Response>
    <Dial action="/handleDialCallStatus.php" method="GET">
        415-123-4567
    </Dial>
    <Say>I am unreachable</Say>
</Response>
```

You could then store or use that SID however you would like.

Please let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you record, RecordingSid is sent along with DialCallSid in parameters scope and that with an action attribute for the <Dial> any verbs after, are unreachable so you'll have to handle multiple <Dial> differently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what I really want is to be able to pair each recording with the child call that initiated it.  In my case I have Sids for the parent call, all child calls, and the recording, I just can't determine which child call initiated which recording.

Comment: i am having the same issue. calling an endpoint that is used to store information about the call and that you later have to stitch together is not ideal at all. i see this reply is 3.5+ years old so i'm not expecting any help here. but it looks like the only way is to maintain your own endpoint, call it when a child call starts with a recording resource as a query param and then use that data to reconstruct the recording structure. Yuck.